# Finding the full name of windows server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

This command lists hundreds of windows servers. How do I select the most popular ones those are displayed on web console while I create a new instance?

```
# aws ec2 describe-images --owners amazon --filters "Name=name,Values=Windows_Server*" --query 'sort_by(Images, &CreationDate)[].Name'
[
    "Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-ECS_Optimized-2017.11.24",
    "Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-ECS_Optimized-2018.01.10",
    "Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-ECS_Optimized-2018.02.21",
    "Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-ECS_Optimized-2018.03.26",
    "Windows_Server-2016-English-Nano-Base-2018.04.11",
...
...
]
```

I am looking for the full name and not just the ami-id.

For e.g. which one of the above is "ami-04ca2d0801450d495"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DescribeImages API call returns the name of the AMI along with the rest of the info. To extract just the name of the AMI, you can run the following command:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids $IMAGE_ID \
    --output text --query 'Images[*].Name'
```

Details about the describe-images command can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html).

Answer (score 0):

This command will return the full name of the given ami ID

```
 aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/aws/service/ami-windows-latest" --region us-east-1 | grep -C3  '04ca2d0801450d495'
```

Comment: Wouldn't `aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-04ca2d0801450d495 --output text --query 'Images[*].Name'` work for you?

Comment: #tried, getting an error #An error occurred (InvalidAMIID.NotFound) when calling the DescribeImages operation: The image id '[ami-04ca2d0801450d495]' does not exist

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you append region to the command and give it a try?

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 you are correct. Can you post the comment as an answer so that I can accept it? It is better than what I have mentioned.